# Design Pattern For Searching Objects in Application

Tags: java, search, design-patterns, jpa

needed some help regarding design patterns. I am creating an app which has different types on Objects stored in databases in separate table.
For eg :
I have 5 kinds of objects A, B , C , D ,E
and i have 5 different tables in database to store each objects .

Now , i want to implement search feature in my application . That means user will be giving a name and multiple object type. For each object type i need to search separate tables for the given names . 
Can any one suggest which design pattern to use for such scenario ?
I am planning to write jpa queries to fetch data from tables

Comment: http://www.oodesign.com/ May be useful.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at something like Lucene/Solr (optionally wrapped with Hibernate Search), especially if your search is going to be text-heavy or do things like snowballing and synonyms.

Comment: i looked into it .. but my search isnt gonna be text heavy .. i just need to match the names .. The things i need to consider is , in real scenario , i wll be having some 20 -30 object types .. So was wondering any specific design i should follow ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to force each problem to fit into a well known design pattern this it might look like a case to use the [*Visitor Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

If you don't have hierarchical structures it reduces to a for loop.

Let your data access objects (DAO) implement a search interface which returns the primary keys (PK):

```
public interface ISearch {
    public int search( String text );
}
```

Collect the results by queried type and PK. 
The implementations could compare to names,remarks, description and so on. You might want to add another method to the interface which returns a text representation of a queried item.