# Do you know the good design pattern for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

Here is my system : 
I have x Mailer objects, each of them are differents instances of the same class (but with different properties)

I have to structure an algorithm to choose 1 Mailer between them :

- I have to evaluate all of the Mailers (is_active, is_active_for_this_period, ...), if the Mailer can be used, put it in a list of "valid" Mailer objects
- Choose randomly between the valid Mailers
- Return the object (to use it after)

Do youknow a design pattern to do that ?
I don't find a good pattern to "choose" an object, given a list of them

Thank you
Florian

Comment: I suppose an [Object Pool](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool) with a filtering algorithm.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking -- the algorithm you've written looks fine. Are you asking how to choose a random element from a list?

Comment: Thanks, Object Pool helps me to structure the list of objects, Now I need to find the pattern to choose/elect/discriminate objects,

Comment: How about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern ?

Comment: Paul Hankin, yes I think my algorithm looks fine, now I want to structure it with the good pattern (especially for class names, method names), to ensure that anyone will understand that code, and to make it more clear

Comment: Zerks, Specification can help me yes, but what would be the "Master" class name that succesively evaluate the specs and choose the right object ?

Comment: When in doubts - call it `...Provider` :-D

Comment: Haha, MailerDecider ? MailerChooser ? ugly

Comment: I think all of this can be structured with the Mediator pattern, with A Mediator class responsible to choose the right Mailer Object, from a MailerPool store

Comment: It sounds like you'd be better writing the code and then asking on codereview.stackexchange.com. I suspect the heavy design ideas touted here may not be helpful for what should be only a few lines of code.

Comment: do you have multiple clients (i.e. folks which ask for objects from object pool.) ? also, since you are keeping all mailer objects in a single pool and not scattered individually, its not a true many - to - many relationship which is usually better suited for Mediator. Also, we generally have to customize standard patterns to suit our needs and sometimes a mix of few too. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389638/design-pattern-for-searching-objects-in-application) helps . If all mailers are of  same type, I would go by @jaco0646 suggestion.

Comment: Further to Paul Hankin's comments: Keep in mind that the only thing that design patterns can add to an already-correct solution is to *efficiently communicate* what you're doing to the next person who reads your code.  But is it really less time and effort for that person to read through 1-2 whole new mostly-boilerplate classes, or to read 2-3 lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the **Strategy** pattern. You might also what to consider the **Composite** pattern for managing the mailers.